# recursively calling the function and counting the members. But it has a bug! Can you spot the problem and fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, global-variables, local

```
def count_users(group):
    count = 0
    for member in get_members(group):
        count += 1
        if is_group(member):
            count += count_users(member)
    return count
```

Comment: Whoever asked you this wants to know whether *you* can.

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment that is meant for you and nobody else to solve.

Comment: This question comes up in the Coursera Python Crash Course.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be like:

```
def count_users(group):
    count = 0
    for member in get_members(group):
        if is_group(member):
            count += count_users(member)
        else
            count += 1
    return count
```

if you don't consider groups as users.

It seems there is no other bug or whatsoever. If the problem remains, you should maybe publish the code for the other parts of the project as well.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def count_users(group):
  count = 0
  for member in get_members(group):
    count += 1
    if is_group(member):
      count += count_users(member)-1
  return count
```

if a member is a group add the number of members in that group - 1 (since u added 1 previously as if it was a menber, but it is not, its a group) here is the code:

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_users(group):
  count = 0
  for member in get_members(group):
    if is_group(member):
      count += count_users(member)
    else:
      count += 1 #Moved from the outside of the "IF" block and put into the ELSE 
                 #part of the IF statement. This removes the double counting. 
  return count

print(count_users("sales")) # Should be 3
print(count_users("engineering")) # Should be 8
print(count_users("everyone")) # Should be 18
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

This is solved here: https://brainly.in/question/17342864

```
def count_users(group):
  count = 0
  for member in get_members(group):
    count += 1
    if is_group(member):
      count -=1
      count += count_users(member)
  return count

print(count_users("sales")) # Should be 3
print(count_users("engineering")) # Should be 8
print(count_users("everyone")) # Should be 18
```

I think this is poor example, as if you break it down it will render lots of name errors - Coursera defines the functions called in the example like is_group or get_members without providing a proper explaination.

Answer (score -1):

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
  count=0
  if n<1:
    return n
  else:
    return n + sum_positive_numbers(n - 1); 

print(sum_positive_numbers(3)) # Should be 6
print(sum_positive_numbers(5)) # Should be 15
```

Comment: I think this problem can be solved using only an If and else Statement

Answer (score -1):

```
def count_users(group):
  count = 0
  for member in get_members(group):
    count += 1 #it is also increasing when the member is a group
    if is_group(member):
      **count -= 1** #if the member is a group, decrease 1 which was increased previously
      count += count_users(member)
  return count

print(count_users("sales")) # Should be 3
print(count_users("engineering")) # Should be 8
print(count_users("everyone")) # Should be 18
```